# How to build a dataframe from specific rows of a text?

Tags: dataframe, text

From a text I would like to extract any value preceded by "name:", "description:" and "column_type:" and built a dataframe from it.
The difficulty is that the text is too long to copy one by one each value and that some values contains""" in them.
I have no idea how to proceed. If anyone could help me please?
Here is a portion of the text:

- name: Volume of PRB Updated Last 3 Months
  description: The total number of PRB's that have been updated in the last 3 months
  formula_id: <3 Months Updated
  properties:
  column_type: MEASURE
  aggregation: SUM

  - name: Problem Sponsor (bfo prb)
    column_id: "fact_problem_1::problem_sponsor"
    properties:
    column_type: ATTRIBUTE
  - name: Tech Notified Customers (bfo prb)
    description: The number of customer who were notified regarding the PRB
    column_id: "fact_problem_1::num_of_notified_customers"
    properties:
    column_type: MEASURE
    aggregation: SUM
  - name: Created Date (bfo prb)
    description: The date the PRB is created
    column_id: "fact_problem_1::creation_date"
    properties:
    column_type: ATTRIBUTE
    calendar: calendar
  - name: Accountable Organization Location Type
    description: Defines the type services the responsible SE Organization is authorized to perform
    column_id: "dim_cc_organization_1::location_type"
    properties:
    column_type: ATTRIBUTE

Comment: Welcome to SO, please try to put short one liner headline describiing your prolem, try to support your question with some example/data .
Refer to this guide to learn more about how you get your question answered more quickly and precisely  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.